# getIntent().getExtras() is some times null in API level 21?

Tags: android, android-intent

As per some google crash report of my app i am seeing NullPointerException,
"Attempt to invoke virtual method `int android.os.Bundle.getInt(java.lang.String)` on a null object reference" but i have made sure and cross checked that intent to that activity always some Extras is set. Can some one suggest me what might be wrong, i am suspecting not overriding onNewIntent, is causing problem but my activity is launched with "`noHistory =true`" flag so `onNewIntent` is never called?

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.custom_alert_dialog);
    mBackToMain = false;
    mDoExit = false;
    int stringMessageId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(name);
    String stringMessage = getIntent().getExtras().getString(fullName);
    initFields(name,fullName);
}




@Override
protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent)
{
    mLog.d("WarningActivity","on new Intent triggered "+ intent.getExtras());
    super.onNewIntent(intent);
    int stringMessageId = getIntent().getExtras().getInt(name);
    String stringMessage = getIntent().getExtras().getString(fullName);
    initFields(name,fullName);
}
```

Comment: Please mention some code for oncreate and OnNewIntent where you are taking data from intent.

Comment: `Intent.getExtras()` may be null on any platform. That's why you use `Intent.get*Extra(String key, * ifNotFound)` methods.

Comment: Hi Eugen, thanks for your comment the problem is in my project the intent is triggered from 100s of places with many extras and it becomes heavy without using bundle.

Comment: Did you got any solution to it?

Answer (score -1):

You may be putting extras right and something else goes wrong so make sure that the extras is not null by checking it first like so:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
if(extras != null) {
    if(extras.containsKey("your key here")) {
        int x = extras.getInt("your key here");
    }
    else {
        Log.d("extras", "No Key");
    }
} else {
    Log.d("extras", "Null Extras");
}
```

and then check your logcat and you should see what's really going on

Comment: Hi Mohamed, thanks for your answer but putting NULL check will bury the problem and it is not ideal solution and the same intent is triggered from many places..

Comment: why would null bury the problem?
the idea here is that you would know what is causing the problem if you put this logic above, that is you'll find "No Key" message in logcat then u know the extras are not there in the first place. @shabarish